# Overlay an td depending on its content

Tags: jquery, css, styles, contains

I´ve a question simular to an solved problem but in my environment the solution doesn´t work.

In a SharePoint there is a table with columns an I want to change the background-color to green of a single td when the content in it is like "Green".

I tried this

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th width="200px">Title</th>
                <th width="100px">State</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Hello</td>
                <td>Green</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>World</td>
                <td>Red</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </tr>
</table>
<script>
    $("td:contains('Green')").css('background-color', '#00FF00');
</script>
```

[My example on JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2TKzc/)

But this is not working at SharePoint table-in-table-structure. Why?
What is the problem? The whole table is paintet in the color of the last value.

Comment: write your code in document.ready

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first include jQuery File

then after

write your code like

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("td:contains('Green')").css('background-color', '#00FF00');
});
</script>
```